# How to get the current active account in tronlink using tronweb?

Tags: javascript, truffle, metamask, tronweb

I'm trying to access the current logged in tronlink account to make an authentication using tronlink for my dapp.
Using metamask and web3 i can get the current active account on MetaMask using:

```
const userPublicAddress = web3.eth.coinbase
```

What's the similar way of doing it with tronweb and tronlink? I havent found about this in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const publicAddress = tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58
```

Comment: this address persists even if TronLink is logged out. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi @VanjaDev! not sure, i don't have the extension anymore to check. Are you able to test?